# ArcPy calculating statistic for pixels within specified neighborhood

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro, focal-statistics

I'm using ArcGIS Pro and I need to calculate the proportion of pixels within 500m for a specified value. I have a raster with coded values of either 0 or 1. For each pixel, I want to calculate the proportion of 1s within a 500m radius. The focal statistics function seems to be the closest tool to accomplish this, but I'm not getting the results I expect.

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set local variables
inRaster = "Hazard_Rating"
neighborhood = NbrCircle(500, "MAP")  # Define a circular neighborhood with 500-meter radius

# Define the constant circle neighborhood with a radius of 500 meters (7854 pixels)
circle_radius = 500
circle_area = 7854
circle_neighborhood = NbrCircle(circle_radius, "CELL")


# Execute FocalStatistics to Calculate the Sum of ones
outFocalStatistics = FocalStatistics(inRaster, circle_neighborhood, "SUM")

# Calculate the proportion of 1s within the fixed circle neighborhood
proportionRaster = outFocalStatistics / circle_area
```

This seems like it should work but I'm getting values above 1 in proportionRaster, and when I check outFocalStatistics the raster attribute table is empty.

Comment: a) use mean as suggested by @user2856 or recalculate circle area

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? why would calculating the mean be the same as the percentage? how will recalculating the circle area help? thank you!

Comment: Mean IS what you call percentage. If you insist on using total, recalculate area to number of cells when using map units = 715398/cellSize/cellSize

Comment: @seak23 did this answer your question, if so https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. If not, how could the answer be improved?

Answer (score 1):

Your current calculation will only be correct if your cell size is 1x1m.

Either:

- Use `FocalStatistics(inRaster, circle_neighborhood, "MEAN")`

  Because you have a grid of 0 and 1 values, mean = sum/count = proportion of 1's in neighbourhood.

  By using mean, you also let ArcGIS handle the edge cases where the focal neighbourhood is not a complete circle. E.g the output at any of the corners will be the proportion of 1s in a quarter circle.
- If you want to treat edge/corner pixels the same (i.e assume the circle can extend outside the bounds of the raster), calculate the circle area in grid cells/pixels so you are calculating the proportion using the same units

  ```
  from arcpy.sa import (FocalStatistics, Raster)
  from math import pi

  inRaster = Raster("Hazard_Rating")

  circle_radius = 500  # m
  circle_area = pi * circle_radius**2
  cell_area = inRaster.meanCellWidth * inRaster.meanCellHeight
  # Estimate the number of grid cells in the circle. This is just approximate
  # See https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/spatial-analyst/nbrcircle-class.htm
  circle_count = circle_area // cell_area  # // is integer division and truncates the result

  # Define a circular neighborhood with 500m radius because we specfied "MAP" not "CELL"
  circle_neighborhood = NbrCircle(circle_radius, "MAP")  

  # Execute FocalStatistics to Calculate the Sum of ones
  outFocalStatistics = FocalStatistics(inRaster, circle_neighborhood, "SUM")

  # Calculate the proportion of 1s within the fixed circle neighborhood
  proportionRaster = outFocalStatistics / circle_count
  ```

Note that the above estimate `circle_count` won't give exactly the number of pixels in `circle_neighborhood`. There are [ways to manually calculate this](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20grid%20cells%20in%20circle), however the simplest way to do this is just to expand the analysis extent by +- radius, fill the outside NoData areas with zeros and crop back to the original extent after calculating the focal mean, e.g.

```
  from arcpy.sa import (FocalStatistics, Raster)
  from math import pi
  
  inRaster = Raster("raster_one.tif")
  
  radius = 500  # m
  
  # Define a circular neighborhood with 500m radius because we specfied "MAP" not "CELL"
  circle_neighborhood = NbrCircle(radius, "MAP")  
  
  extent = inRaster.extent
  
  xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = extent.XMin - radius, extent.YMin - radius, extent.XMax + radius, extent.YMax + radius
  
  with arcpy.EnvManager(extent=arcpy.Extent(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)):
  
      # Execute FocalStatistics to Calculate the Sum of ones
      outFocalStatistics = FocalStatistics(Con(IsNull(inRaster), 0, inRaster), circle_neighborhood, "MEAN")
  
  with arcpy.EnvManager(extent=extent):
      outRaster = ApplyEnvironment(outFocalStatistics)
```